# How do I export & use SWC for RSL with Flash Pro CS5?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5, rsl

I want to create a RSL with Flash Pro CS5 and then use it with another Flash file. I've created the following example:

RSLLib.fla

- Create the file
- Create a new MovieClip symbol called `Circle`, export it for ActionScript as `Circle` and tick "Export for runtime sharing" with the value "RSLLib.swf"
- In publish settings tick "Export SWC"
- Export the file and now we have "RSLLib.swc" and "RSLLib.swf"

User.fla

- Create the file
- On the first frame of the timeline add the following ActionScript

  addChild(new Circle());
- In ActionScript Settings, in the Library Path create and entry pointing to RSLLib.swc and choose Link Type: "Runtime shared library" with RSL URL "RSLLib.swf"
- Export the file and you'll see that Flash Pro CS5 crashes

Am I doing anything wrong here?... Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All works fine for me. Sounds more like a system/sand-box problem, maybe try changing folders or launching it via http.

Also, little detail I noticed in your example : you don't have to tick the "Export for runtime-sharing" in the library if you are handling the import via SWC etc. Shouldn't crash flash anyway but just so you know ; )

Comment: It was the specific configuration that made Flash crash, I couldn't figure out exactly what, but a different path and a clean slate make the above example work.